# Error occurred while MicroCloudFoundry installation

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am using Fedora-16 (64 bit) Operating System. 
I have got registered with CloudFoundry and get download "*micro-1.2.0.zip*" and 
"*VMware-Player-4.0.2-591240.x86_64.bundle*". I have successfully installed the "*VMware-Player*". Then how can install "*micro cloud foundry*" correctly?

When extract it and run the "micro.vmx" file, then I have got several warring messages and finally got this error message as,

**This kernel requires an x86_64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU**

If some one know how I can over come this problem or what is the correct way to install "*MicroCloudFoundry*", please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the processor compatibility as well.
Here is the link where you can check the processor compatibility:

http://downloads.vmware.com/d/details/processor_check_5_5_dt/dCpiQGhkYmRAZQ